# JS & Regex: how to replace punctuation pattern properly?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given an input text such where all spaces are replaced by n _ :

```
Hello_world_?. Hello_other_sentenc3___. World___________.
```

I want to keep the _ between words, but I want to stick each punctuation back to the last word of a sentence without any space between last word and punctuation. I want to use the the punctuation as pivot of my regex.

I wrote the following JS-Regex:

```
str = str.replace(/(_| )*([:punct:])*( |_)/g, "$2$3");
```

This fails, since it returns :

```
Hello_world_?. Hello_other_sentenc3_. World_._
```

Why it doesn't works ? **How to delete all "_" between the last word and the punctuation ?** 
http://jsfiddle.net/9c4z5/

Comment: I don't believe JS has a `:punct:` option in its regex implementaiton.

Comment: Have you an idea of what should I use instead then ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [following regex](http://jsfiddle.net/9c4z5/1/), which makes use of a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
str = str.replace(/_+(?=\.)/g, "");
```

It replaces all underscores which are immediately followed by a punctuation character with the empty string, thus removing them.

If you want to match other punctuation characters than just the period, replace the `\.` part with an appropriate character class.

Comment: I need all the punctuations, my end-users are multilingual, use multiple scripts.

Comment: @Hugolpz Have you tried to implemented what I explain in the last paragraph?

Comment: I'am begginer, I'am faking that I understand what is "character class" but want the precise answer, while I actually just don't understand your answer ("character class"). Just that.

Comment: @Hugolpz Just list the punctuation characters that you want to match: `/_+(?=[.?!;,])/g`

Comment: Marius: thanks. So a "character class" is the list of characters you place within `[]` I guess

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have `:punct:` in its regex implementation. I believe you'd have to list out the punctuation characters you care about, perhaps something like this:

```
str = str.replace(/(_| )+([.,?])/g, "$2");
```

That is, replace any group of `_` or space that is immediately followed by punctation with just the punctuation.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9c4z5/2/